# How do I debug a Python extension written in C?

Tags: python, debugging

How do I debug a Python extension written in C? I found some links that said we need to get the Python debug built, but how do we do that if we don't have root access? I have Python 2.7 installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile a debug-enabled version python in your home folder without having root access and develop the C extension against that version.

Comment: The installation instructions can be found here: http://docs.python.org/using/index.html